# Something like Collections.rotate for map

Tags: java, list, dictionary

Not looking for any code help just yet, just some advice.

I'm devising a scheduler that takes a text file input and schedules weekly games for all teams. I have this working, and now I'm looking at expanding it to hold results. At the moment I read all the teams into a list. and use Collections.rotate to rotate the list in order to randomize the fixtures.

I was thinking of using a Map to hold the team and number of wins, however rotate doesn't appear to work for map. Is there a similar function that I'm missing, or something that I have overlooked?

Comment: How about adding a field wins, and setters and getters for your team class? That way you can still keep it in a list and use Collections.rotate as before. Lookup is not O(1) like map but with a list of teams that should not be a problem, few elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't want to rotate the Map itself, but it sounds like what you want to do is rotate a view of the Map's *keys*.

So in pseudo-code, you could do something like

```
//make a copy of the keys of the map
List keys = new ArrayList(yourmap.keys())
Collections.rotate(keys)
//iterate over the keys of the map in the new rotated order
for key in keys:
    Object value = yourmap.get(key)
    // do something with this value
```

Comment: You need to make sure the map keys are in the desired order to start with.

Comment: correct, although the original question mentions "use Collections.rotate to rotate the list *in order to randomize* the fixtures" which seems somewhat incorrect - it's not truly random - `Collections.shuffle()` sounds like a better fit.

Comment: Indeed - not sure if the OP wants to randomize or to rotate.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 main, non-specialised, implementations of the `Map` interface in the JDK:

- `HashMap` which is not ordered - that is not going to help you
- `TreeMap` which is ordered based on some comparator - probably not easy to adapt to your use case
- `LinkedHashMap` which is ordered either by insertion order or by access order

In your case, you could use a `LinkedHashMap` using access order (you create one with [a special construtor with the parameter `accessOrder` set to `true`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap%28int,%20float,%20boolean%29)) and every time you access one of the items it will get reordered automatically to the tail of the map. A full iteration cycle will keep the order unchanged.

Comment: "... every time you access one of the items it will get reordered automatically to the tail of the map." Accessing does not move anything unless you instantiate it using the special constructor, and by default, all other constructors make the map insertion-order.

Comment: @Brian I specifically mentionned *`LinkedHashMap` using **access order*** which is created with the constructor you linked to.

Comment: My point is just that it's not obvious how to create it, that's all. The link wasn't working using the `[]()` for some reason, so here it is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap(int,%20float,%20boolean)

Answer (score 2):

Rotate might work with LinkedHashMap, this is how to rotate map by one element

```
Iterator<Entry> i = m.entrySet().iterator();
Entry e = i.next();
i.remove();
m.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```